# Does the winner of British Grand Prix keep the Golden British Grand Prix trophy?

Tags: formula-1

I always watch the highlights for every F1 race. I know that the winner of each Grand Prix will get a trophy and a medal. But recently, I found out that at the British Grand Prix, there are two types of trophy that are presented to the winner:

- The first trophy is the Grand Prix trophy, that is given to the drivers in 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place.
- The other trophy is the Golden Trophy, where the winner of the British Grand Prix will have their name engraved on the bottom part of the trophy.

My question is, does the winner get to keep the other trophy for himself? Or does it need to be returned later on?

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Grand_Prix_Trophy) (emphasis mine):

> The official, perpetual trophy is awarded to the winner of the British Grand Prix **and then returned to the Royal Automobile Club, where it is permanently housed.**

So they do not get to keep the golden trophy permanently.